# Sections in html

Tags: html, jsp

i have a wep page. in navigation bar i have links. but when i click link it doesnt open in section part. How can i fix it?

```
<div id="header">
<h1>Library</h1>
</div>

<div id="nav">
<ul>
  <li><a href="admin.jsp">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="BookInf.jsp">Books</a></li>
  <li><a href="memberInf.jsp">Members</a></li>
  <li><a href="Messages.jsp">Messages</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="footer">

</div>
```

Comment: What does "open in section part" mean?  When you click on a link, it takes you to that page.  What isn't working here?

Comment: there is not error in this code. but i want when i click link will open in frame

Comment: Then you're going to want to look up HTML frames.  There aren't any in this code.  A Google search for "HTML frames" finds documentation, tutorials, and examples.

Comment: You would need to add an iframe first and for all hyperlink you would need target element defined as Name of iframe. I assume you have web xml configuration defined for those jsps. As David mentioned there are lot of available references online to get it done. http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe_target

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is add an `<iframe>`, then give it an ID, and set the `target=""` of each `<a>` to that ID. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/xj0skuas/1/

```html
<div id="header">
<h1>Library</h1>
</div>

<div id="nav">
<ul>
  <li><a href="admin.jsp" target="frame">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="BookInf.jsp" target="frame">Books</a></li>
  <li><a href="memberInf.jsp" target="frame">Members</a></li>
  <li><a href="Messages.jsp" target="frame">Messages</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<iframe name="frame">
<div id="footer">

</div>
```